# PHP MySQL database design

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a user table which has username,user_id,password and email fields.

The user can post updates,can subscribe to users and can friend people.

What is the best way to design my database in order to store the count of the updates, subcribers and friends of a user?

Should i add 3 more fields in the user table and just increase the count of these 3 columns?

Thanks.

Comment: DON'T store friends in a column in the user table.... learn to normalize your database designs, and add a user_friends table... then you won't hit so many constraints

Comment: I thing it was only a typo and OP meant 3 more fields in the user table.

Comment: Whether the OP meant friends or fields, the answer is still the same: don't add them in the users table... normalize

Comment: I meant fields, i just want to get the count of these 3 items of a user as fast as possible.Of course the updates are in a separate table as subscribers and subscriptions are.I am talking about their count.

Answer (score 1):

You can make 3 tables: friends (user1_id,user2_id), updates(user_id,content),subscribe(user1_id,user2_id).
If the database is big and you don't want to count the friends each time, you can add a field in users table and update it every time a friend is added/deleted
Maybe drawing a diagram would help:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model

Answer (score 1):

First I'd try to calculate

> the count of the updates, subcribers and friends of a user

on the fly, something like

```
select count(*) from user_updates where user_id = :uid
select count(*) from user_subcribers where user_id = :uid
select count(*) from user_friends where user_id = :uid
```

If you have performance problems with this approach, then you can consider adding these count fields to user table, but you have to be careful to maintain them.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i understand your question but i think the best way to do this is to make a table for each of this functions, you can link those tables with the user_id field. Like so:

Table 'Users' :

```
*user_id*
username
password
email
```

Table 'Friends':

```
id
*user_id*
friendids
```

You can then get the users with something like

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user_id = '$userid'
```

Answer (score 0):

Either create a separate table with that user meta data or add them as new columns. Either way is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you meant to type "columns" instead of "friends" in that last sentence.

That's one way to do it.

You should think about the entities, relationships, and cardinalities when you design.  Do you want to keep track of timestamp for each update?  If yes, I'd make that a separate table with a one-to-many relationship to user.  Same for subscribers and friends.  The answer depends on how you choose to model the problem.  There's no right or wrong answer, but there are tradeoffs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is faster to read if you have separated relations and content, however if you have only content and generates relations from it, the result sometimes could be more accurate. So, it depends.